# D3, VueJS, axes of chart not rendering

Tags: d3.js, vuejs2

I am trying to add D3 histogram to a VueJS component and I can't get the axes to appear correctly. The only thing I see rendered is the tip of the y-axis.

here is my js for the chart component:

```
export default {
  name: "Histogram",
  props: {
  },
  mounted() {
    this.generateBars();
  },
  data: () => ({
    title: 'Bar Chart'
  }),
  methods: {
    generateBars() {
      const sample = [
      {
        language: 'Rust',
        value: 78.9,
        color: '#000000'
      },

      ...

      {
        language: 'Clojure',
        value: 59.6,
        color: '#507dca'
      }
    ];
      const margin = 60
      const width = 1000 - 2 * margin;
      const height = 600 - 2 * margin;

      const svg = d3.select("svg");

      const chart = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);

      const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0])
        .domain([0, 100]);
      
      chart.append('g')
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

      const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([0, width])
        .domain(this.sample.map((s) => s.language))
        .padding(0.2)
      
      chart.append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));
      
    }
  }
};
```

My template for the component is simply the chart itself:

```
<template>
  <div id="container" class="svg-container" align="center">
    <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
    <svg />
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is what I see:
[image]

After further examination, I think the footer is covering the bottom of the chart. Not sure why it does not move down to accommodate the additional content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to set width and height for svg (via html or js).

```
<svg width="1000" height="600"></svg>
```

And remove "this" in line:

```
.domain(this.sample.map((s) => s.language))
```